# Interacting with FullCalendar in my developer console

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using the [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io) in my webpage and am trying to interact with it using my Browser Console.

HTML:

```
  <p>
    <button id='prev'>prev</button>
    <button id='next'>next</button>
  </p>

  <div id='calendar'></div>
```

JS:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
      header: false // don't display the default header
    });

    calendar.render();

    document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.prev(); // call method
    });

    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.next(); // call method
    });

  });
```

In my console if I run `calendar.next();`, it says calendar.next() is not a function.

Can someone explain why and what is the correct way to interact with the calendar?

I've also tried using

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
calendarEl.next();
```

But returns the same error.

Comment: have you tried making the `calendar` variable global? Right now its scope is restricted to within the DomContentLoaded callback? I mean like `var calendar; document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
      header: false // don't display the default header
    });`...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `calendar` variable global

```
var calendar; 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); 
  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { 
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
});
```

Then in console type `calendar.next();`

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery `next` - please refer to this link 
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next'); // call method
});
```

Comment: fullCalendar v4 does not use jQuery any more. (You can tell the code above is v4 because it does not use jQuery...). See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 . P.S. Your CodePen link is empty as well...doh

Comment: The new version of fullcalendar doesn’t require jQuery

Comment: Hope you have added fullCalendar JS in header,did you ?

Comment: @RajdipKhavad clearly the OP has done that, otherwise the calendar would not show at all. That is not the issue. Read the question again.

Answer (score -1):

Running `calendar.next()` seems to work for me

```
const el = document.querySelector("#calendar");

const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(el, {
  plugins: ['dayGrid']
});

calendar.render();

setTimeout(() => {
  calendar.next();
},2000);
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRQpwo

Comment: The question is about accessing the calendar object from the developer console of the browser, not from the code built into the page